# Why aren't the texts in my input box and select box aligned/padded equally in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am struggling with a problem that I cannot solve or understand. I have a form with one text input and one select drop-down. I am using Bootstrap 5, and I want to reduce the default left padding in all form controls. Therefore I have added a `padding-left:0.3rem` in my style definitions. Here's my example code:

```css
.form-control,
.form-select {
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form style="width:200px">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="John">

      <label for="country" class="form-label">Country:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="country" name="country">
        <option>USA</option>
        <option>South Africa</option>
        <option>Sweden</option>
        <option>Netherlands</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expect a result where "John" and "USA" is aligned with same padding in their form controls. But take a look at the image below. "USA" is padded more than "John". Why is that, and how can I solve it?

[image]

**UPDATE:** After testing this on different browsers I have learned that the problem only appears for Firefox. On Chrome and Edge the padding/alignment seems to be correct. So, now I wonder if I can use some CSS-trick to make it work on Firefox as well?

Comment: [Doesn't occur for me in Firefox on Win10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sqxK.png) using the snippet above. Maybe it has been fixed. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative margin to the `<option>` elements, too. You added left padding on `.form-select` to create a little space from the left side of the box. Can you also now add `margin-left: -10px` to `<option>` to bring it back toward the left a bit? Or put an additional few pixels padding on the Name input.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `rem` for your padding which is a relative size. So the actual size will be different. Try to remove the `padding-left`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form style="width:200px">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="John">
    
            <label for="country" class="form-label">Country:</label>
            <select class="form-select" id="country" name="country">
                <option>USA</option>
                <option>South Africa</option>
                <option>Sweden</option>
                <option>Netherlands</option>
            </select> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The gap will be much smaller now, even it's still not actually aligned.

Comment: This is not working for Firefox. There's still a problem with different margins, even if it's only 2-3 pixels.

Comment: Like I said, I just make the gap smaller. I'm using Firefox too and here's the result https://imgur.com/a/fBGisEQ .

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed in Bootstrap v5.3.0.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="USA">
    <label for="country" class="form-label">Country:</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="country" name="country">
      <option>USA</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Firefox 123.0 on Windows 11.

Answer (score -1):

it's not about select or input element. it's about what character you are writing for example "U" have this extra line on top of it in some fonts that makes it to have whiteSpace around it.
maybe using another font would fix your problem.

Comment: No, that's not the case. If I enter "Japan" instead of "USA" it will generate the same indentation, even if it begins with the same character as "John"

Answer (score -1):

Use the following css for your labels.

```
.form-label {
      margin-left: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: can also use "padding-left: 0.3rem".

Comment: This only aligns the labels. I am concerned with the alignment/padding of the texts in the input/select fields. The problem only arises in Firefox - not on Edge/Chrome.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please delete.